# Hardhat: How to "spin up" a local JSON-RPC fork node at a specific block number with my new contract deployed in it?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I can "spin up" a local fake blockchain in Terminal using

```
$ hardhat node
```

I can also make it fork the real mainnet using Alchemy, even pin it to a specific block `N`. Other local applications can then connect at `http://localhost:8545` and interact with the forked local chain until I press `Ctrl+C` in that Terminal window and my local `JSON-RPC` node disappears. So far so good.

**My question is: How do I combine this feature with deploying a contract?**

How do I do **BOTH**:

1. Spin up the forked chain at block `N`, so it is usable via port 8545 (launch an `JSON-RPC` server that runs until I stop it)
2. And while my forked chain spins up, how do I deploy a test contract "into it" (probably will increase my block number from `N` to `N + 1`)?

**What I have tried:**

I have tried a deploy script. It seems that I can "spin up" the desired forked chain at block N momentarily, but at no time is it accessible via port 8545 to other applications.

Inside the script, I can deploy a contract with the usual deploy commands, and even interact with my contract.

What I really need though, is a "live" (accessible via port 8545 or 8546) forked chain with my brand new contract "in it", so another app (that is not launched via `hardhat` or `hh` commands) can interact with it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like it was said by Franco in the [previous answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/111760/70336) you can use the `--network` tag to deploy to the node you're running. For easy deployment, you can use the [hardhat deploy](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy) plugin.

I would like to add that you make the app you're running locally accessible to other people by running `ngrok` for example.
Since the node you're running is on `localhost:8545`, you could run `ngrok http 8545` which will give you a url like `https://XXXX-XXXX.ngrok.io`
You can then share that link with other people (they can input it [into their Metamask](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043227612-How-to-add-a-custom-network-RPC) or you could use it in your web application. It's a great way of testing your app quickly from your localhost

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Hardhat task without specifying a network with the `--network` param, a temporary, in-process Hardhat network is created for that task. That network doesn't open any port, it's just available for that task.

The `node` task is a built-in task which starts an HTTP server, making the Hardhat network available (in `localhost:8545` by default).

So what you can do is start a `node` in one terminal, and then run any other task (for example, your deploy) in another one using `--network localhost`. This is just a default network that connects to `localhost:8545`, there's nothing special about it.

I wrote a more in-depth explainer [here](https://hackmd.io/@fvictorio/hardhat-networks-and-providers) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing an RPC from an existing script can be done by calling the `node` task.

1. Make sure you've setup forking for hardhat in `hardhat.config.ts`
2. Create a new script file to run at `start.js` with the code:

```js
async function start() {
 const { run } = require("hardhat");
 // deploy your contact here
 await run("node");
 await new Promise(() => setTimeout(()=>{}, 2147483647)); // until ctrl+c
}
start() // + then/catch
```

3. Run it with `npx hardhat run start.js --network hardhat`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are all correct and I figured it out, it's a matter of connecting to the spun up 8485 network!